# Full Calendar week view width of event is not correct

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I am using full calendar scheduler, now in week view I am having issues all events are not getting displayed in proper UI if lots of events are there. This is working fine in month and agenda day views but not in week view only.
Is there any process we can fix the min-width of the event in week view and calendar can pick the overall width accordingly even scroll is fine.

Any suggestions?
[Snap for week view UI with lots of events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeh3M.png)

Comment: We can't see your code, but have you set `https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap` to `false` by any chance? That might help. Also consider whether you could make your overall calendar wider. And lastly consider whether displaying this many events at once is actually useful - perhaps some filtering would be helpful. And if you are really using Scheduler (as you've tagged), then consider adding resources to your agenda view: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vertical-resource-view which might improve the layout if the events are associated with specific resources

Comment: Hello, Yes I am using full calendar scheduler. Resources are 68 so can not use vertical view. and per resource 10 items per day so week view is not looking good. Thanks.

Comment: Well to be honest that many resources and events is always going to be a problem, unless you show it on an enormous TV screen or something. And it will be confusing to users to have all that information shown at once, they won't be able to take it in easily, and probably they won't be interested in most of it either. You need to think about the best way of displaying the information. Maybe you should allow the user to select which resources they want to show together or something. It depends on your requirements. But I think this is really an issue of good UI design, not a technical difficulty